# En mi función consigo los datos pero cuando los pido desde mi método me da UNDEFINIED

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, backend, undefined

EDIT 1

Reformulo mi pregunta para que sea mas comprensible y expongo el caso, en primer lugar adjunto todo el archivo:

```
'use strict'

const console = require('colorful-console-logger');  
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
//const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
//const moment = require('moment');
const db = require('../db');

const NewUser = ({nombre, apellido, correo, pass, rol}) => {
    db.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("MySql - ERR", "No se pudo establecer la conexión con la base de datos");
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                conn.query('INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, correo, pass, rol) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [nombre, apellido, correo, pass, rol], (err, userStored) => {
                    if (err || !userStored) {
                        console.error("MySql - ERR", "Se ha producido un error mientras se intentaban guardar los datos del usuario")
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    if (userStored) {
                        console.log("MySql - OK", "Se han almacenado correctamente los datos del usuario");
                        resolve(userStored);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });
};

const GetUserByEmail = (correo) => {
    return db.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("MySql - ERR", "No se pudo establecer la conexión con la base de datos");
                reject(err);
            } else {

                conn.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?', [correo], (err, user) => {
                    if (err || !user) {
                        console.error("MySql - ERR", "Se ha producido un error mientras se intentaban buscar los datos del usuario")
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    if (user) {
                        console.log("MySql - OK", "La consulta de busqueda ha finalizado con exito");
                        //console.log("user", user);
                        resolve(user);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
}

var controller = {
    test: function(req, res){
        console.log("usuarios: test - OK", "Una respuesta de testeo del controlador 'usuarios' ha sido servida correctamente");
        return res.status(200).send({
            msg: "Esta es la respuesta afirmativa del metodo 'test' de 'usuarios'"
        });
    },

    register: async function(req, res){
        const body = req.body;
        var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);

        body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(body.pass, 10);
        //var result = await NewUser(body);
        console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);

        return res.status(200).send({
            msg: "El metodo 'register' del controlador 'usuarios' ha devuelto una respuesta afirmativa"
        });
    }
}

module.exports = controller
```

donde **db** contiene el pool de la conexión a mysql

Problema:

En la constante GetUserByEmail el siguiente código (obiamente descomentado) me devuelve un usuario si existe en la base de datos y un objeto vacío si no existe:

```
//console.log("user", user);
```

La cuestion es que en el metodo register: que esta dentro del objeto controller
el siguiente codigo me devuelve usuario duplicado **undefinied**:

```
        var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);
        console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);
```

Objetivo:

Donde me devuelve undefinied me gustaria recibir el objeto con el usuario si esta duplicado o el objeto vacio si el usuario es nuevo

Añadido:

La llamada al metodo register la ejecuto de la siguiente forma:

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const UsuariosController = require('../controllers/usuarios');

router.get('/usuarios/test', UsuariosController.test);
router.post('/usuarios/register', UsuariosController.register); // <-- asi

module.exports = router;
```

Este es mi archivo de rutas, estas rutas las consulto desde postman para ver si funcionan

Comment: Ummmm amigo una pregunta, antes de editar mi pregunta de nuevo me gustaria saber como haces la llamada al metodo register de tu namespace controller, solo la llamada, es decir, que parametros le pasas y como la llamas por ejemplo, puede que el problema este ahí...

Comment: edito mi pregunta y te lo añado

Comment: Hola @franciscojavierlopezperez , veo que ya te apoyaron, al parecer es en el manejo de promesas y async/await, creo que a todos nos pasa, que se nos complica al inicio, manejar de forma correcta las peticiones asincronanas, veo que estás en la parte del login e imagino que estás iniciando el proyecto, por lo que te recomendaría utilizar mejor un ORM, que es más organizado y limpia a la hora de escribir código, personalmente he utilizado Sequelize, pero veo que también está Prisma, que parece interesante, éxitos.

Comment: Como me recomendaste he pasado a utilizar Sequelize, y de momento me va bien, igualmente dejo la pregunta abierta por si otros usuarios pueden obtener información valiosa a partir de las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Partamos de lo siguiente, primero, debes retornar la promise sea que se entre o no o en alguna de las dos condiciones, de lo contrario si se entra en el primer if, como no se esta retornando una promise dentro, los metodos `then` y `catch` no se podrían usar y `await` no tendría efecto, que por cierto, muy organizado y bonito el código, te felicito:

```
const GetUserByEmail = (correo) => {
    return db.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("MySql - ERR", "No se pudo establecer la conexión con la base de datos");
                reject(err);
            } else {

                conn.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?', [correo], (err, user) => {
                    if (err || !user) {
                        console.error("MySql - ERR", "Se ha producido un error mientras se intentaban buscar los datos del usuario")
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    if (user) {
                        console.log("MySql - OK", "La consulta de busqueda ha finalizado con exito");
                        console.log("user", user);
                        resolve(user);
                    }
                })

            }
        })
    });
}
```

En segundo lugar debes retornar el resultado `db.pool.getConnection` lo cuál si o sí siempre ahora será una `promise`, de lo contrario no tendría sentido crear la `promise` ya que en la propia función estarías devolviendo siempre undefined.

Lo tercero es que aquí:

```
register: async function(req, res){
    const body = req.body;

    //Se te olvido usar await
    var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);

    console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);
    body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(body.pass, 10);
    const result = await NewUser(body);
    return res.status(200).send({
        msg: "El metodo 'register' del controlador 'usuarios' ha devuelto una respuesta afirmativa",
        result
    });
}
```

Con esto ya debes ver el resultado de `GetUserByEmail` dentro de `register:` sin problemas.

Muy bien, he decidido clarificar un poco mas las cosas, así que cree una simulación un tanto vaga de tu código para poder mirar que pasa por detras y ver si funciona o no, aquí el ejemplo de mi simulación:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    const informacionDePrueba = {
        body: {
            correo: "example@example.com"
        }   //Solo un ejemplo
    }

    const db = {
        pool:{
            getConnection: async(callback)=>{
                return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        res(
                            callback(
                                false, {
                                    query: async function(queryStat, correo, callback){
                                        /*
                                            No voy a usar lo demas por que solo es una simulación,
                                            pero supongamos que ya usamos el correo para hacer la
                                            comprobación en la base de datos.
                                        */
                                        return await new Promise((res, rej) =>{
                                            setTimeout(()=>{
                                                res(callback(false, "kowalski"));
                                            }, 1000)
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            ));
                    }, 2000);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    const objeto = {
        register: async function(req, res){
            const body = req.body;
        
            //Se te olvido usar await
            var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);
        
            console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);
            
            //Lo demas que hay en tu codigo...
        }
    }

    const GetUserByEmail = (correo) => {

        return db.pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("MySql - ERR", "No se pudo establecer la conexión con la base de datos");
                    reject(err);
                } else {
    
                    conn.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?', [correo], (err, user) => {
                        if (err || !user) {
                            console.error("MySql - ERR", "Se ha producido un error mientras se intentaban buscar los datos del usuario")
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        if (user) {
                            console.log("MySql - OK", "La consulta de busqueda ha finalizado con exito");
                            console.log("user", user);
                            resolve(user);
                        }
                    })
    
                }
            })
           
        });
    }

    objeto.register(informacionDePrueba);

}
```

Como vemos funciona correctamente, ahora, no me voy a dedicar a explicar en detalle las siguientes cosas:

- informacionDePrueba
- db
- GetUserByEmail

El primero y el segundo no lo explicare por que simplemente es la información y simulación que hecho para hacer como si se hiciese una consulta a alguna base de datos.

`GetUserByEmail` no la explicare tampoco porque realmente la función y su cuerpo no cambiaron en nada como yo la tenia planteada en la respuesta.

Por ultimo lo que si voy a explicar es que esta parte de aquí de tu código:

```
register: async function(req, res){
    const body = req.body;

    var duplicateUser = GetUserByEmail(body.correo);

    console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);
    body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(body.pass, 10);
    const result = await NewUser(body);
    return res.status(200).send({
        msg: "El metodo 'register' del controlador 'usuarios' ha devuelto una respuesta afirmativa",
        result
    });
}
```

Lo que hice simplemente fue meterla dentro de un objeto en mi código y guardarlo en una variable para que no quede anonimo el objeto, ademas le agregue `await` y lo llame `objeto`:

```
const objeto = {
    register: async function(req, res){
        const body = req.body;

        //Se te olvido usar await
        var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);

        console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);

        //Lo demas que hay en tu codigo...
    }
}
```

No es necesario que lo hagas por supuesto ya que tu ya tienes tu propio objeto...

Checa lo siguiente en tu código:

```
router.get('/usuarios/test', UsuariosController.test);
router.post('/usuarios/register', UsuariosController.register);
```

La primera vez haces una petición `get` hacía `usuarios/test` la segunda un `post` hacia `/usuarios/register`, el que uses `post` o `get` no afecta en nada, pero y que tal si enrealidad lo que devuelve la respuesta en tu propio código y no en postman es undefined usando la ruta de `register` en alguno de los dos valores que obtiene el callback?, ya sea en `res` o en `req`, compruebalo desde el código mirando que hay cuando haces post:

```
router.post('/usuarios/register', (req, res)=>{

    console.log(req, res);

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Riven creo que te he entendido bien 1 no debo poner el if / else y 2 necesito un .them y un .catch. hasta hay perfecto pero no soy capaz de formularlo correctamente en mi codigo. ¿podrias mostrarme un ejemplo de como hacerlo correctamente?

Comment: Amigo, revisa mi respuesta, en la respuesta esta tu código modificado, así como esta mi respuesta debe funcionarte. De todas maneras si no funciona editare mi respuesta y pondre un ejemplo diferente, que simula tu pregunta, ya que yo no tengo petición de donde hacer para sacar esos valores. Revisa ambas partes del código porfavor.

Comment: He probado el codigo que me has dejado en tu respuesta y sigue devolviendome undefined, si puedes poner un ejemplo que simule esto te lo agradeceria y muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Checa de nuevo la respuesta, acabo de editarla y puse un ejemplo mas completo funcional de tu código.

Comment: He estado probando tu codigo pero desgraciadamente sigue sin funcionarme (no me refiero a que este mal, es más en stack overflow cuando lo ejecuto funciona a la perfección) el caso es que sobre mi codigo aun no consigo que funcione. He reformulado la pregunta y he añadido todo el codigo. Muchisimas gracias por tu atención y disculpa las molestias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas `async/await` para las promesas el flujo es distinto. Si quieres capturar el error tienes que usar `try/catch` y en tu caso no lo tienes por eso nunca tienes acceso al valor `reject` de `GetUserByEmail`.

Igualmente, en tu código no veo que devuelvas un objeto vacío si no que devuelves el error.

Aunque yo lo haría de otra manera.

1. Comprobar si existe el usuario con ese correo
2. Si existe hacer un reject
3. Si no existe crear uno nuevo hacer un resolve sin nada.

Porque si tienes un error en tu consulta por x motivos no te creará el nuevo usuario. Así es mas acorde al flujo del `try/catch`. Pero ahi tu mismo como veas que mejor funciona para tu caso.

```
var controller = {
    test: function(req, res){
        console.log("usuarios: test - OK", "Una respuesta de testeo del controlador 'usuarios' ha sido servida correctamente");
        return res.status(200).send({
            msg: "Esta es la respuesta afirmativa del metodo 'test' de 'usuarios'"
        });
    },

    register: async function(req, res){
        const body = req.body;
        try {
          var duplicateUser = await GetUserByEmail(body.correo);
          console.log("usuario duplicado", duplicateUser);

        } catch(e) {
          // usuario no encontrado aqui haces tu logica de crear usuario nuevo
          body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(body.pass, 10);
          var result = await NewUser(body);
        }

        // y la respuesta que toque
        return res.status(200).send({
            msg: "El metodo 'register' del controlador 'usuarios' ha devuelto una respuesta afirmativa"
        });
    }
}
```